# Serilog: unable to get the rollingfile working

Tags: logging, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, serilog

Scenario: ASP.NET MVC 6 web application.

Here are the package imported in `project.json`:

```
"Serilog": "2.3.0",
"Serilog.Extensions.Logging": "1.3.1",
"Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile": "3.2.0",
"Serilog.Settings.Configuration":  "2.2.0"
```

Here is `appsettings` configuration

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Verbose",
        "Override": {
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "Debug",
            "System": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
        {
            "Name": "RollingFile",
            "Args": {
                "path": "logger-{Date}.log",
                "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} [{Level:u3}] ({Application}/{MachineName}/{ThreadId}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                "fileSizeLimitBytes": 16384
            }
        }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
    "Properties": {
        "Application": "Sample"
    }
},
```

Here is `Startup` constructor

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                  .SetBasePath( _environment.ContentRootPath )
                  .AddJsonFile( "appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true )
                  .AddJsonFile( $"appsettings.{_environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true );

Configuration = builder.Build();

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                 .ReadFrom.Configuration( Configuration )
                 .CreateLogger();
```

In configure method I have

```
loggerFactory.AddConsole();
loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
```

Where is supposed to be written the file? Can be a problem related to write permission?

**EDIT**

Followed @Sanket suggestions but still does not work. I have also switched to kestrel to see if it was working on the console but still no luck. Here's what I see:

```
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method MyCompany.MyProject.Host.Controllers.HomeController.Index MyCompany.MyProject.Host) with arguments (
(null)) - ModelState is Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor[1]
      Executing ViewResult, running view at path /Views/Home/Index.cshtml.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action MyCompany.MyProject.Host.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MyCompany.MyProject.Host) in 2614.9118ms
```

This is very strange to me as in the Home Controller in Index action I just have

```
public IActionResult Index() {
    _logger.LogDebug( "Index in HomeController called!" );
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In startup, you can specify path of rolling file like this-

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.RollingFile(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "Serilog-{Date}.txt"))
    .CreateLogger();
```

---

**UPDATE:**

In appsettings.json, change **path** argument to **pathFormat**

```
"path": "logger-{Date}.log",
```

to

```
"pathFormat": "logger-{Date}.log",
```

and file will be created at project location.

Refer this [link](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile)

---

**UPDATE2:**

In Startup constructor, change serilog logger like this-

From

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                 .ReadFrom.Configuration( Configuration )
                 .CreateLogger();
```

To

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                 .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
                 .CreateLogger();
```